# Concatenate data in different rows based of of matching data in other columns while keeping all data

Tags: vba, excel

hi i am having some issues coding with vba in excel. I have a mailing list that has a row for each person however there are many people who are in the same households as another person. both have the same addresses and have a matching household ID. I need to combine the names of people with the same Household ID and address so that MS word can make mailing labels for each house.

The code needs to find rows with the same household ID,Salutation, Solicit Description, Street 1, Street 2, Street 3, City, State, Zip Code. and combine the text in the top and bottom row with an "&" symbol for Mail Name, Alum Y/N, Donor Y/N, Solicitable. Where the result is the top rows info before the & and the bottom row after. All data is already sorted so duplicate household id are together. I dont code much and am not use to a lot of the naming conventions. I pieced this together from some forums. I get and error with the key section.example excel pictures are attached, hopefully they are view able. Any help is welcomed. Thank you:)

```
Sub merge_A_to_D_data()
Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, str As String, dbl As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=.Columns(4), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Key3:=.Columns(5), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                Key4:=.Columns(6), Order4:=xlAscending, _
                Key5:=.Columns(7), Order5:=xlAscending, _
                Key6:=.Columns(8), Order6:=xlAscending, _
                Key7:=.Columns(9), Order7:=xlAscending, _
                Key8:=.Columns(10), Order8:=xlAscending, _
                Key9:=.Columns(11), Order9:=xlAscending, _
                Key10:=.Columns(12), Order10:=xlAscending, _
                Key11:=.Columns(13), Order11:=xlAscending, _
                Key12:=.Columns(14), Order12:=xlAscending, _
                Key13:=.Columns(15), Order13:=xlAscending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    lr = .Rows.Count
    For rw = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(rw, 2).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 2).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 4).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 4).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 5).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 5).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 6).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 6).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 7).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 7).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 8).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 8).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 9).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 9).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 10).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 10).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 11).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 11).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 12).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 12).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 13).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 13).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 14).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 14).Value2 And _
            .Cells(rw, 15).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 15).Value2 And rw < lr Then
             .Cells(rw, 3) = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(rw, 3), .Cells(lr, 3))), Chr(59))
             .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(lr - rw, 1).EntireRow.Delete
             lr = rw - 1
        End If
    Next rw
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[before code run, pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx1fB.jpg)

[after code run, pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5PzZ.jpg)

Comment: First:  You picture only has data to column M (or column 13) and you are sorting up to column 15.  Since you are using CurrentRegion, this will give you an error.  Delete the the keys for columns 14 and 15.   Second: You are not sorting column 1 (which is your household ID).  Does this have to be done in place or could you combine the fields (records) in another worksheet?

Comment: Sorry about that, I copy and pasted my data into a new worksheet to edit it for the post. so the columns in the code are actually the correct ones in the sheet. My bad. The data can be moved to a new sheet for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on your data pictures you posted.  If you data is in different columns, you will need to apply those changes to the code.  This sorts your data and the move/combines the rows in a new sheet called "Labels".  The sort is for the entire worksheet since you use of CurrentRegion wasn't explained.

```
Sub Concatenate_data()
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
With ws.Sort
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 1)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 2)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 4)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 5)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 6)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 7)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 8)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 9)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 10)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 11)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 12)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 13)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 14)
.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, 15)

 .Header = xlYes
 .SetRange Range("A1:O" & ws.Rows.Count) 'this is a static range
 .Apply
End With

WB.Sheets.Add(After:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Labels" 'creates new worksheet
        Worksheets("Labels").Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@" 'formats household ID to be text so you don't lose leading zeros
        Worksheets("Labels").Rows(1).Value = ws.Rows(1).Value ' header row
  'lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
               rwlabel = 2
    For rw = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(rw, 1).Value = ws.Cells(rw - 1, 1).Value Then 'only checks for duplicate household ID.  You can add more conditions as you need
           Worksheets("Labels").Rows(rwlabel).Value = ws.Rows(rw).Value ' copy entire row

            Worksheets("Labels").Cells(rwlabel, 4).Value = ws.Cells(rw, 4) & Chr(38) & ws.Cells(rw - 1, 4)
            Worksheets("Labels").Cells(rwlabel, 5).Value = ws.Cells(rw, 5) & Chr(38) & ws.Cells(rw - 1, 5)
            Worksheets("Labels").Cells(rwlabel, 6).Value = ws.Cells(rw, 5) & Chr(38) & ws.Cells(rw - 1, 6)
            rw = rw - 1 'increment  passeed the duplicate line on you data (activeworksheet)
        Else
          Worksheets("Labels").Rows(rwlabel).Value = ws.Rows(rw).Value  'copies entire row that has no duplicate household ID

        End If
                     rwlabel = rwlabel + 1
    Next rw
End Sub
```